# Using multiple "ands" in a list

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I am writing a paper, and I don't know if the following sentence is grammatically correct...

> For years dichotomies have controlled humanity in multiple areas: mind and body, truth and falsity, male and female, and democrat and republican.

Comment: Lot of questions on this site re. use of semicolons to separate non-singular items in a list. Perhaps that is what is concerning you ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the sentence is correct. Semicolons are appropriate if the items in the list contain commas themselves. Your case is bolstered by the fact that the reader expects a list of pairs.